# Swift UnitTesting testing 2 optional variables

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I've 2 variables for which i want to be sure that both are not nil at same time, one variable must not nil to pass unit test.

Following code can test for one object not be nil.

> I've 2 variables dataArray & dataObject I just want to make sure that
>   at a time one of them must have value

```
CoreWebService.sendRequest(requestURL: WebURL.testFeed, paramters: params) { (sender: RequestCallback<BaseResponse<DataJson>>) in

        switch sender {
        case .failed(let error):
            XCTFail("Error\(error.localizedDescription)")
            break
        case .success(let object):
            XCTAssertNotNil(object.dataArray, "data must not nil")
            break
        }
        xctExpect.fulfill()

    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout) { (error) in
        XCTAssertNil(error, "Test time out\(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two optional properties of different type, say `a` and `b`, you can switch over the tuple `(a, b)` for a `case (.none, .none)`, which would correspond to both properties being `nil`. If not matching this case, at least one of the properties are non-`nil`). E.g.

```
let a: Int? = 1
let b: String? = nil

// ...

switch (a, b) {
    case (.none, .none): XCTFail("...") // fail case
    case _ : () // otherwise _at least_ one of 'a' and 'b'
                // is non-nil
}
```

Or, simply

```
// fail case w.r.t. 'nil'-ness?
if case (.none, .none) = (a, b) {
    XCTFail("...")
}
```

If both of your optional properties are of the same type, say `Int?`, then you can simply test the the `nil`-ness of the expression `a ?? b`, which will be `nil` only if both `a` and `b` are `nil`.

```
let a: Int? = 1
let b: Int? = nil

// ...

XCTAssertNotNil(a ?? b, "Both properties are nil ...")
```

Comment: if you could have a look on this question, I'm stuck at that too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778641/objectmapper-array-or-object-based-on-data

Answer (score 1):

You can try `flatMap` like this…

```
let dataArray: [String]? = ["a", "b"]
let dataObject: Int? = nil

// Create an array of your objects
let allObjects: [Any?] = [dataArray, dataObject]

// Use flatMap to return an array of non-nil objects
let nonNil = allObjects.flatMap({$0})

// Check count is > 0
XCTAssertGreaterThan(nonNil.count, 0)
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer works too but I can only accept one !

Comment: if you could have a look on this question, I'm stuck at that too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778641/objectmapper-array-or-object-based-on-data